# Pulling an item from listview

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to pull a value from a listview and display it in a label.  If I wanted to pull "Data Three" from the First Item, I was attempting the following:

```
private void frmNotifications_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Items.Clear();
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("First Item");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data One");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data Two");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data Three");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data Four");
    Settings.Items.Add(item);
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Second Item");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data One");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data Two");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data Three");
    item.SubItems.Add("Data Four");
    Settings.Items.Add(item);
    lblData.text = Settings.GetItemAt(1, 4).Text;
}
```

My final line is kicking back `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: Looks like `Settings.GetItemAt(1, 4)` is returning `null` or `lblData` itself is `null`.  Have you attached a debugger to take a look and see which is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is get the value to the "text" information for the item.  This can be achieved by:

```
var newVariable = ListView1.Items[1].SubItems[1].Text
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  Will pick as answer once it allows me.